# swift - how to merge sticker to recording video with pause/resume ability

Tags: ios, swift, video, avfoundation, video-recording

I want to create an app like [MSQRD](https://itunes.apple.com/vn/app/msqrd-live-filters-face-swap-for-video-selfies/id1065249424?l=vi&mt=8)

I have a record video via `AVFoundation`. I want to add a face sticker on my video realtime

I can detect face via `CIDetectFace` and get the face location.

But I don't know how to merge them then creating final video.

Can we edit the `CMSampleBuffer` and add layer sticker on it?

I also want to have pause and resume recording ability.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: This question is too broad to get any traction, please ask one specific question and include code samples to show what you have tried.